# Webpack 4. Compile scss to separate css file

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Im trying to compile scss into a separate css file with no luck. As it is now the css gets into the bundle.js together with all js code.
How can i separate my css into its own file?

This is how my config looks:

```js
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/main.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/dist"
    },
    watch:true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: { presets: ["es2015"] }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 71):

Other answers gave me just headache as they were not working. I did a lot of googling and I realized you can compile `scss` into separate `css` file without using any additional plugins

**webpack.config.js**

```js
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: [
            __dirname + '/src/js/app.js',
            __dirname + '/src/scss/app.scss'
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
            filename: 'js/app.min.js',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [],
                }, {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: { outputPath: 'css/', name: '[name].min.css'}
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

**package.json**

```js
    {
      "name": "...",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "...",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {},
      "devDependencies": {
        "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode='production'"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "...",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

**Dependencies:**

```
npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli file-loader node-sass sass-loader
```

**How to run JS and SCSS compilation**

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I've been spinning my wheels for hours trying to get this sorted; css-loader was giving me all sorts of problems and nothing on the internet helped.  Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks!!! Finally an answer that actually worked exactly as required. I spent days on this problem!

Comment: wow! thanks a lot mate. I was like searching this for weeks. I was like how webpack doesn't provide this. Even the docs say only one output can be given. Well finally! or i was about to add gulp in addition

Comment: Thank you so much, worked exactly as desired! I think a lot of dev hours would be saved if this solution was included in the official documentation for sass-loader @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader

Comment: You should use Dart Sass (`npm install --save-dev sass`) instead of node-sass.

Comment: Should note that this is for Webpack v4 and lower (will still work in webpack v5) but in webpack v5 the file-loader is built in now via assets https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ making this solution even easier..

Comment: Thanks a lot! In a project of mine I had many `style.scss` files in each directory and it only generated a single `style.css` file, so i had to change `[name]` with `[folder]` after reading the doc a bit. thanks again! https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#folder

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need 'node-sass', not sure if others would. But for me, when i tried installing that, it was giving me a bunch of errors. so i tried without it and it works. i'm only using webpack for compiling scss->css so maybe that's why.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/). This will extract your css into a separate file.

There are a few parts of your webpack.config.js file you'll need to add to, or change.

You'll need to require the plugin at the top of the file:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
```

A plugins property is also required in the modules object:

```
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "[name].css",
    chunkFilename: "[id].css"
  })
]
```

And you'll need to change your scss rule. Note the test is slightly different to include .scss files (probably best to name you scss files .scss) and the addition of the sass-loader which you'll need to install with npm. The loaders in the 'use' array operate in reverse order, so sass-loaded goes first, converting scss to css, then the css-loader and then extract plugin extracts the css out again to a separate file:

```
{
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      "css-loader",
      "sass-loader"
    ]
}
```

So I think your config file will change to this:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/main.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/dist"
    },
    watch:true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: { presets: ["es2015"] }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  "css-loader",
                  "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: "[name].css",
          chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Understood. When you have installed the npm module, how do you get it to actually work? I mean, how would you change the webpack-file?

Comment: Thanks! it helped me a bit, but it does not create any css file. I have updated the code in my post.

Comment: @fortyfiveknots hmm, ok. I will look later, but until this evening. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @fortyfiveknots I have update my answer. I never had the loaders quite right.

Comment: It can be done without mini-css-plugin. please see the answer of my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035376/webpack-file-loader-with-sass-loader/55045199#55045199

Answer (score 17):

to update **@Fusion** 's [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60029923/12368419):

from https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader:

> **DEPRECATED for v5**: please consider migrating to **asset modules**.

the official docs (https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) mention that clearly: as of webpack v5, `raw-loader`, `url-loader`, `file-loader` loaders are now depricated and replaced with **Asset Modules**, and new 4 module types: `asset/resource` (which replace `file-loader`), `asset/inline`, `asset/source`, `asset` are introduced.

so, the new way to compile scss to separate css file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    __dirname + '/src/js/app.js',
    __dirname + '/src/scss/app.scss'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'js/app.min.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [],
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,

        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'css/[name].min.css'
        },

        use: [

          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { outputPath: 'css/', name: '[name].min.css'}
          },

          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

the big advantage is that **Asset Modules** is a webpack built-in and you won't even need to install any 3rd module.

refer to:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#resource-assets
- https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-output-filename

## Update:

you may realise that webpack generates an extra/unwanted/unexpected js file for non-js files (css, scss ...) despite the methode you use `file-loader` or `asset` modules, in this case, https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fix-style-only-entries comes handy to solve this limitation.

```
const path = require('path');

const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require("webpack-fix-style-only-entries");

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    __dirname + '/src/js/app.js',
    __dirname + '/src/scss/app.scss'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: 'js/app.min.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [],
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,

        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'css/[name].min.css'
        },

        use: [
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin({ extensions:['scss'] }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks @cizario. Could you please add how we could add the source mapping for scss too? So we can know where each line of css has come from what line in scss and which file?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `node-sass` from npm.

And if you are using webpack for bundling your site you should follow next steps:

`npm install node-sass`

In package.json sections scripts add following:

```
scripts: {
   "scss": "node-sass --watch src -o src"
}
```

First `src` is location of `sass` files and `-o src` is output path where `css` files will be served.