# Webpack file-loader with sass-loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader, webpack-file-loader

I am new to nodejs and get a problem when trying to use sass with it.

> The following information is just fictional, but it represents the
>   actual condition.

---

**THE SCENARIO:**

I have the following folder structure:

```
frontend/
 - scss/
  - style.scss
 - main.js
webpack.config.js
```

**Goal**:

I want to compile the `style.scss` to `style.css` using webpack and put it inside `dist/frontend/css/` directory, so it should be resulting this path: `dist/frontend/css/style.css` and create the following folder structure:

```
dist/
 - frontend/
   - scss/
     - style.scs
   - main.js
frontend/
     - scss/
      - style.scss
     - main.js
webpack.config.js
```

---

**THE CODES:**

**main.js**

```
import `style from "./scss/style.scss";`
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
     mode: "development",
     entry: {
       main: "./frontend/main.js"
     },
     output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist/frontend"),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: "[name].js"
     },
     module: {
       rules: [ 
        {
           test: /\.(s*)css$/,
           use: [
             {
               loader: "file-loader",
               options: {
                 name: "css/[name].[ext]"
               }
             },
             "style-loader/url",
             "css-loader?-url",
             "sass-loader"
           ] 
         }
       ]
   }
```

---

**THE RESULT:**

I get this message:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './scss/style.scss' in 'E:\project_name\frontend'`

---

**THE QUESTIONS**

1. Why is that happening?
2. What is the correct codes to achieve the **Goal**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the message said, this path is not valid: `'./scss/style.scss'`. There are typo when defining the path. The folder is supposed to be `sass` instead of `scss`.

The following configuration will work to achieve the **Goal** mentioned in the question:

```
 module: {
   rules: [
      {
    test: /\.(s*)css$/,        
    use: [
      "style-loader/url",
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "css/[name].css"
        }
      },
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

It works like `Mini CSS Extract Plugin`, but does not generating additional `.js` files for each `.css` file when used to convert multiple `.scss` files into different `.css` files.