# How to generate side css with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have a Laravel Application with a `webpack.config.js` quite similar to this one:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: { app: ['./app/Http/app.js'] },
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/'),
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.(sass|scss)$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

This config will generate a bundle javascript `app.js` which is good for my frontend. However I would like generate another bundle from sass files:

Input:

- `app/assets/sass/print.sass`

Output:

- `public/css/print.css`

What should I change on my Webpack config to do this additional side generation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394789/webpack-4-compile-scss-to-separate-css-file

Comment: @VadimHulevich Not really an answer. `MiniCssExtractPlugin` does not seem to go along with `style-loader` and it is not possible to generate a side css.

Comment: @nowox, I thing you also need to create list of entry point for each bundle AFAIK

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?